# Javascript Math Operation Results in Wrong Answer

Tags: javascript, floating-point

Can someone explain to me whats going on here? When I print out the DeltaTime variable its a reasonable number. When I use it in any mathematical operation it causes the result to be really high.

```
var Test = 0;

function
Update(DeltaTime)
{
    Test += DeltaTime;

    console.log(DeltaTime);
    console.log(Test);
}

function
Render()
{
    Context.clearRect(0, 0, DefaultCanvasWidth, DefaultCanvasHeight);

    RenderPlayer();
}

function
GameLoop()
{
    CurrentTime = Date.now();
    var DeltaTime = (CurrentTime - LastTime) / 1000;
    LastTime = CurrentTime;

    Update(DeltaTime);
    Render();

    requestAnimationFrame(GameLoop);
}

GameLoop();
```

Here is the output

```
main.js:31 0.02
main.js:32 1423402123.8969905
main.js:31 0.029
main.js:32 1423402128.9259906
main.js:31 0.022
main.js:32 1423402133.9479907
main.js:31 0.029
main.js:32 1423402138.9769907
main.js:31 0.032
main.js:32 1423402144.0089908
main.js:31 0.022
main.js:32 1423402149.0309908
main.js:31 0.028
main.js:32 1423402154.058991
main.js:31 0.023
main.js:32 1423402159.081991
main.js:31 0.029
main.js:32 1423402164.110991
main.js:31 0.019
main.js:32 1423402169.129991
main.js:31 0.03
main.js:32 1423402174.159991
main.js:31 0.033
main.js:32 1423402179.192991
main.js:31 0.021
main.js:32 1423402184.213991
main.js:31 0.029
main.js:32 1423402189.242991
```

Comment: Seems that LastTime is initialized with zero (or not initialized), so the first value of DeltaTime is probably in the order of Time() -- that is ,the number of milliseconds since January 1st, 1970. Try adding `var LastTime = Date.now();` before calling GameLoop() (or immediately after initializing Test).

Comment: Yup had LastTime initialized to zero. Thank you for pointing that out to me. Cant believe I was left scratching my head for that long and didn't check my time variables.